# Files downloading again after they've been deleted

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

I deleted about 900 files, when I connected my computer they all started downloading again.

I don't want them to come back. In file management I only see an option to delete one file at a time. I am currently using the Windows beta on Windows 7. Once all the data is off I can switch OSs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want them out of your Ubuntu One account all together? I'd say connect your computer, *then* delete the files and wait for things to sync the normal way. Doing it the other way around probably doesn't let Ubuntu One "know" you wanted them gone.